# How to add symetrical deviance residuals line to the plot?

Tags: r

I have a chart like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data=predicted.data, aes(x=rank, y=probability.of.edu)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=edu), shape=18, stroke=2, size=5) +
  xlab("Index") +
  ylab("Predicted probability of education independence") +
  labs(color = "Education") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#b961e8", "#ed9458")) 
p
```

[image]

I would like to add symetrical deviance residuals line to this plot.

It will look like:

[image]